# Android: caching SQLite entities in memory

Tags: android, sqlite, caching, greendao, dbflow

What approach should I use to minimize disk i/o when reading/writing to SQLite database in Android? Something like ConcurrentHashMap with WeakReferences? [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/)? [GuavaCache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained)?

Should I use built-in caches in ORMs like [GreenDao](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/sessions/), [DBFlow](https://agrosner.gitbooks.io/dbflow/content/Caching.html), [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#Object-Caches)? The documentation is very vague when it comes to clearing these caches... When should I clear them? Should I?

I tried to enable cache in ORMLite, but there were bugs: nulls instead of empty foreign collections after cascade delete/insert of entities...

So what's the best practice? Maybe not to use cache at all and just to read/write from DB asynchronously to ensure fresh data?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the reads to the database with a [Lru cache](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) in order to reduce the memory footprint (since it won't grow indefinetely). However, you will need to invalidate the records in case they are updated / removed from the storage.

Short video intro [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5ON3iwx78M).